# How to align two TextViews to make them read like a sentence

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout with two TextViews. I'm currently trying to align & constrain the two TextViews in order to make them read like a sentence in ConstraintLayout.

When TextView 1 gets long, I want TextView 2 to wrap to the next line, so that together - the two TextViews still appear as one piece of text.

The reason I'm doing this with separate TextViews, is that the my first and second textviews have different sources of data and are bound to separate fields in my ViewModel.

Please see the photo below:

[image]

Is this possible in ConstraintLayout or any of the other Layouts?

Comment: If i may ask why are you not using Single TextView and concat the string as single text and set after second source has returned the text.

Comment: This could definitely work, thanks! I didn't think of concatenating the strings. @MalikSaifullah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each Android view fills a continuous area on a screen. Your second *TextView* violates this characteristic insofar as it will have two disjointed areas and that is not permitted.

I suggest that you use a single *TextView* and observe the two sources of data to update the view. You might be able to use something like [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) to do this.

Comment: Great idea - could definitely work. Thanks!